# java - searching a word in a map with list as value

Tags: java, string, collections, frameworks

I have a .txt:

1. line:  x, Munich, c, e, f
2. line:  y, Berlin, ad, uf
3. line:  z, Hamburg, of, bf

All words are separated with a ','.

The first 2 strings of one line in this txt goes to a constructor. The 3. and following strings goes to a List.
The key for example is: a b in form of a constructor
The value is a ArrayList with: c, e, f. So 3 elements.

```
String filePath = "....txt";

        List<String> itemlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<Corporation, List> corp = new HashMap<Corporation, List>();

        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(",", 3);
            if (parts.length >= 3) {
                String name = parts[0]; // key=name, value= address
                String address = parts[1];
                String info = parts[2];
                itemlist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(info.split(",")));
                Corporation cor = new Corporation(name, address);
                corp.put(cor, itemlist);
            }
        }
```

That everything works fine.
Now i need to search a string in one of the ArrayLists in the Map.
For example i search the string "bf" and it prints that it found the string and where with the right key of the map. For example with "bf": it will print "bf found at "z, Hamburg"".

```
for (Entry<Corporation, List> entry : corp.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals("bf")) {
                System.out.println("Found at " + );
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            } else {
                System.out.println("String not found.");
            }
        }
```

This part of my code does not work as i want. How do i do it right?

Comment: Please define "does not work" Output/expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (entry.getValue().equals("bf"))` is comparing a `List` with a `String`.

Try this `if (entry.getValue().contains("bf"))`

Comment: with System.out.println(corp.entrySet()); i get the output:

Comment: [Corporation [name=x, address= Munich]=[ c,  e,  f ], Corporation [name=y, address= Berlin]=[ ad,  uf], Corporation [name=z, address= Hamburg]=[ of,  bf]]

Comment: I think you have a space before your entries in the list. Try `entry.getValue().contains(" bf")` and see if you get the `"Found at"`

Answer (score 0):

```
entry.getValue().equals("bf")
```

compares a List vs a String. That can never be true.

You most likely wantet this:

```
entry.getValue().contains("bf")
```